# Trying to emulate a hardware camera with a stream from a raspberry pi/picam?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I have a raspberry pi and pi cam v2 connected to wifi. I am trying to stream the camera feed to a laptop over wifi, then make that stream appear as if it were a hardware camera on the laptop. I want to do this in order to get it into some other software that requires a hardware camera (can't rewrite this software, just have to work around it).

I am running ubuntu 18.04 on the laptop. From my research, this should be very possible using some combination of ffmpeg and vfl2loopback. I started out by installing this library to stream the camera to a webserver: https://github.com/silvanmelchior/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface This works, and I am able to access the camera stream in my browser at http://10.0.0.47/http I set it up with no username/password for simplicity. I believe the camera port is 80 based on nmap output.

I am now trying to redirect the stream on my ubuntu laptop. Based on my research and experimentation, this command is the closest I've come:

ffmpeg -re -i http://10.0.0.47/html -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0

(or also the same with port 80 instead of /html, not sure if this matters): ffmpeg -re -i http://10.0.0.47:80 -map 0:v -f v4l2 dev/video0

This seems to work at first, but then produces the following error:

http://10.0.0.47:80: Invalid data found when processing input

From googling, this may be due to the wrong kind of stream coming out of the rpi_cam_web interface, but I am not sure if this is true and if so how to fix it. I also investigated the html code of the page that accesses the webserver, and I can see that it is sending a series of jpgs, that change constantly with timestamps in the file name. So maybe this the issue, but again, unsure.

Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I tried another method, which seems to get a little further on, but am still running into issues:

(on the pi): raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 320 -h 240 -fps 30| cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8000/}' :demux=h264

-->this starts a stream that I am able to succesfully view in VLC media player

(then on the host system): gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.0.0.47:8000/ ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video4

I tried various devices, like /dev/video0, /dev/video1, etc. They all produce '"/dev/videoX" is not a output device', except for video4, which seems to be working at first, but then errors out with:

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1: Internal data stream error. Additional debug info: gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1) Execution ended after 0:00:00.082360368

Any idea what might be going wrong there?

Thanks again!

Edit 2:

I may have it working with the following sequence of commands:

(on pi): raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 320 -h 240 -fps 30| cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8000/}' :demux=h264

(on host computer): ffmpeg -f h264 -i tcp://10.0.0.47:8000/ -f v4l2 -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video0

This doesn't throw any errors, but I'm not 100% sure it's working cause I haven't been able to load the stream in software I'm trying to get the camera feed into yet. I tried testing it with this website tool:

https://test.webrtc.org/

and the tool allows me to select "Dummy Video Device 0x0000", which I'm pretty sure is it, but it then tells me "no video device detected", fails to find any camera in its testing, and then the same Dummy Video Device doesn't show up as an option on subsequent page reloads. So I think there's something wrong about how I'm passing the stream

Answer (score 0):

This website shows how to stream RPi to OBS:
https://www.instructables.com/Webcam-Over-WiFi-for-OBS/

Then you could use OBS Virtual Camera to simulate a hardware camera.

(I personally use OBS Virtual Camera, but have not used it with RPi.)

Alternatively you could try this:
https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/how-to/use-raspberry-pi-as-pc-webcam

Comment: Thanks! I am following the instructions on the first link. Upon running ./picam.sh, I get the following errors: [003bccb8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00334b58] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[6260fc58] h26x demux error: this doesn't look like a h264 ES stream, continuing anyway
[626058b0] main stream error: unknown query 0x30e in demux_vaControlHelper
Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: @JohnDoe are you using a RPi camera? if so the second link specifically uses that, whereas the first one uses a Logitech camera.

Comment: as for the errors you are getting, I have no idea

Comment: have you tried adding 10.0.0.47:8000 as a media source in OBS?

Comment: I am using an RPI cam. I have not used OBS yet, do you think that may be able to do the rerouting for me?

Comment: ob sshould be able to route it using virtual camera as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: gotcha, I'll try that out, thanks!