# How to Use Public Video Stream as Webcam Feed?

Tags: video, streaming, webcam, camera, zoom-meeting

I would like to setup an existing public 'live stream' as a 'camera' feed in Windows 11.

The goal would be while on a zoom/skype/teams etc, in my list of Cameras, I can pick an option that relays a live stream from a public camera online.

For example, while on a zoom I would like to select a 'camera' that results in just showing a stream from a public site such as: https://www.earthcam.com/usa/southcarolina/greenville/?cam=giraffe_ext

[image]

I assume this would require an app/program etc.
For example, I have 'Droid Camera' which is a program that allows streaming from my android devices camera that is using the program, and adds 'DroidCam Source' to my list of cameras.

I am thinking there may be a way to use an application and tell it my 'camera' is a url or similar.

Comment: Potentially a solution at https://superuser.com/questions/1642369/trying-to-emulate-a-hardware-camera-with-a-stream-from-a-raspberry-pi-picam

Comment: Cool I'll give it a read thank you!